# converting a number to binary form using overloaded methods

Tags: java

I am working with the next code, which basically converts an hexadecimal number into its binary form. First of all i have to declare a variable type int, byte or short, and then inicialize it with an hexadecimal number, and then it has to print the binary number like this:

int h = 0x1 -> 00000000 | 00000000 | 00000000 | 00000001 (32 because an int has 32 bits)

byte h = 0x1 -> 00000001 (byte has 8 bits)

short h = 0x1 -> 00000000 | 00000001 (short has 16 bits)

I already have the function that converts it, and it works fine, the problem is that I have to create three overloaded methods(one for int, another for short, and the other for byte), the parameters would be the hexadecimal number and the type, but how can get the type of the variable without using the Java API(I am not allowed to use it).

```
public class Bits {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        int value = 0xFFFFFFFF;
        memoryRAM(value);
    }

    public static void memoryRAM(int value)
    {
        int i,bits;
        bits = 32;
        char binary[] = new char[bits];
        for(i = bits-1;i >= 0;i--)
        {
            if((value&1) == 1)
               binary[i] = '1';
            else if((value&1) == 0)
               binary[i] = '0';
            value >>= 1;
        }
        printArray(binary);
    }

    public static void printArray(char binary[]){
        for(int i = 0;i < binary.length;i++)
            System.out.print(""+binary[i]);
    }
}
```

So far, I have created the method with the value parameter, but I need another parameter with the type of the variable(int,short,byte).

Answer (score 1):

Having three methods, one for each type, will automatically sort the variable into the correct method, and from there, you can hard code the methods to do the type-specific calculations

for example, if you have:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    byte b = 4;
    int i = 1000;
    short s = 123;
    someMethod(b); //this will automatically choose the "byte" method
    someMethod(i); //this will automatically choose the "int" method
    someMethod(s); //this will automatically choose the "short" method
}

public static void someMethod(byte b){
    //do byte specific stuff
}

public static void someMethod(int i){
    //do int specific stuff
}

public static void someMethod(short s){
    //do short specific stuff
}
```

or to get type of primitive variable:

```
byte b = 4;
String type = "";

if(byte.class.isInstance(b))
    type = "byte";
if(int.class.isInstance(b))
    type = "int";
if(short.class.isInstance(b))
    type = "short";
```